# How to put a services on angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-factory

I'm trying to write a module on angular js for put my service (file: utils/productos.js) then load it as a dependency for my module ventas (ventas/ventas.js) but

I get the next error:

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'utils.producto' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$injector/nomod?p0=utils.producto angular.js:63:11
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module webui due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module utils.producto due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'utils.producto' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.10/$injector/nomod?p0=utils.producto
minErr/<@http://localhost/cat-dog/web/app/js/angular.js:63:12
module/<@http://localhost/cat-dog/web/app/js/angular.js:1764:1
ensure@http://localhost/cat-dog/web/app/js/angular.js:1688:38
module@http://localhost/cat-dog/web/app/js/angular.js:1762:1
loadModules/<@http://localhost/cat-dog/web/app/js/angular.js:4094:22
forEach@http://localhost/cat-dog/web/app/js/angular.js:323:11
loadModules@http://localhost/cat-dog/web/app/js/angular.js:4078:5
loadModules/<@http://localhost/cat-dog/web/app/js/angular.js:4095:40
forEach@http://localhost/cat-dog/web/app/js/angular.js:323:11
lo
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('webui', ['ngRoute', 'utils.producto', 'ventas']);
```

main.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ventas/ventas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="utils/productos.js"></script>
```

ventas/ventas.js

```
angular.module('ventas', ['ngRoute', 'utils.producto'])

        .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/ventas', {
                    templateUrl: 'ventas/ventas.html',
                    controller: 'VentasCtrl'
                });
            }])
```

utils/producto.js

```
    angular.module('utils.producto').factory("buscadorProductos", buscadorProductos).factory("autocompProductos", autocompProductos);

    function buscadorProductos($http) {
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define service as module first like `angular.module('utils.producto',[])`

**Code**

```
 angular.module('utils.producto',[]).factory("buscadorProductos", buscadorProductos).factory("autocompProductos", autocompProductos);

    function buscadorProductos($http) {
```

Comment: Yes. Is that the trouble. Thanks so much. I was losing my head.

Comment: yes, I have to wait 9 minutes to do that. I was waiting.

Comment: @user92083452 may I know why this answer mark has been removed?